# jScrollPane horyzontal scrollbar on top

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

i got set up a jScrollPane horyzontal scrollbar but right now the scrollbar is horyzontal but on top(this means the scrollable content is below the scrollbar), i need the contrary: scrollbar below, scrollable content on top, how can i make this?
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you have got the scrollable content below the scrollbar. By default it appears above the scrollbar (e.g. see this example: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html ). What version of jScrollPane are you using? Do you have a URL showing the problem?

---

Update based on the clarifications given below:

You can use CSS to put the scroll bar ABOVE the content. e.g.

```
.jspHorizontalBar
{
    top: 0;

}
.jspPane
{
    margin: 16px 0 0;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi , I want the contrary of the example you're showing, i want the scrollbar on top

Comment: Your question says that you want the content on top and the scrollbar below. Now that you have clarified I'll update my answer...

Comment: Thanks a lot, how did you find about this? is it in the documentation?

Comment: Do you know if the property scrollbarWidth works the same way with horyzontal scroll? i am having a hard time setting up this simple option.

Comment: I found out about this because I am the author of jScrollPane. This specific case isn't mentioned in the documentation but you should be able to figure it out by examining a generated jScrollPane in Firebug and playing with the CSS. Re your second comment, there is no scollbarWidth option in jScrollPane 2. Maybe you can ask a new question and clarify what you are asking?